# Why the sum() function doesn't work in the SQL view?

Tags: sql, sum

The task is as following:

> By using the views BPA and BooksInStock, create a new view that
> displays the total number of books published by Info Press that are
> currently in stock. Name the view InfoPressStock. Again, see the
> view's result table below: The result attribute is named "stock
> total".

```
select * from infopressstock;
stock total
-------------
         102
(1 row)
```

A bit detail about the two views:

BooksInStock:

```
Name    Data type   Length  NOT NULL    Default Constraints
book    character varying   48          
copies in stock integer
```

BPA

```
Name    Data type   Length  NOT NULL    Default Constraints
book    character varying   48          
publisher   character varying   32          
author  character varying   32
```

I tried to create a new view from other two views BPA and BooksInstock by using the following code:

```
CREATE VIEW InfoPressStock AS 
SELECT SUM('copies in stock') AS "stock total" 
FROM (booksinstock INNER JOIN bpa ON booksinstock.book = bpa.book)
WHERE publisher = 'Info Press';
```

However, the system told me that the:

> ERROR:  function sum(unknown) is not unique

Comment: Use double quotes for column names, `SUM("copies in stock")`

Comment: `'copies in stock'` isn't a column reference, it's a string. You're trying to sum up some text. As per the previous comment, escape the column name with `"copies in stock"` instead. Even better, specify the table the column comes from and don't put spaces on your column names; `SUM(booksinstock.copies_in_stock)`

Answer (score -1):

Remove the inverted commas from your sum function where you should use the name of your required column and remove brackets from your join condition

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).